# android : Views in constraintLayout not updating

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have view(activeListeningView), i want to make it visible when i get response from api call.
my problem is activeListeningView becomes visible but viewpager covers it and doesn't care about margins.
I tried many ways but nothing works

```
<com.irantracking.ptt.common.view.ActiveListeningView
        android:id="@+id/active_listening"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/active_listening" />
```

Comment: Change android:layout_height="56dp" to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: why is viewpager height 0dp?, you should `match_constraint` instead

Comment: it fills space between activeListeningView and bottom of activity

Comment: try using match_constraint on the viewpager instead of 0dp, 0dp only works on the children of  linearlayout when they have weight

Comment: base on documentation "Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT""